# finding daylight saving indication based on offset and suffix of time zone

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

i am using earth tool webservice  to find time zone based on lat long. I am getting offset and suffix in the webservice.

[Earth Tool Webservice](http://www.earthtools.org/timezone/43.902345/-100.933285)

Now the problem, i am facing is i need to get time zone from the offset and suffix and determine if there is daylight saving in the area or not. how can i do this?

Comment: Do you have to use that particular web service? Why do you need to know whether the offset includes DST out of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.Net has a nice TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime, but unfortunately you don't have enough info to create an instance.

You should however be able to do something like this:

```
var offSet = -7;
var utcDateTimeStr = "2011-09-10 22:15:38";
var localWithDSStr = "10 Sep 2011 15:15:38";

// utc time
DateTime utcDateTime = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
                           DateTime.Parse(utcDateTimeStr), DateTimeKind.Utc);
// time taking into account daylight savings
DateTime localWithDS = DateTime.SpecifyKind(
                           DateTime.Parse(localWithDSStr), DateTimeKind.Local);
// time not taking into account daylight savings
DateTime localWithoutDS = utcDateTime.AddHours(offSet);

// is the time given adjusted for daylight savings
TimeSpan diff = (localWithoutDS - utcDateTime);
bool isDayLightSaving = diff.Hours != offSet;
```

Comment: thanks but what i am trying to do is i have a offset and suffix and i get the local time of the server and get the Universal time from that `TimeZone tz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
                DateTime SystemTime = DateTime.Now;

                DateTime Usertime = tz.ToUniversalTime(SystemTime).AddHours(int.Parse(TimeStamp));`

Comment: Universal time is in the feed already, so is the timezone's local time. I don't understand how your code relates to your question regarding the feed, or what you are trying to do. To can get *your* server UTC time using `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using returns if there is daylight saving on that lang+lot, you don't have to find it out from offset and suffix.

See this:

> dst
>   Whether or not the localtime and isotime elements include
>   daylight saving time. If they do, the value of this element will be
>   True. If they do not, the value will be False. If it can't be
>   determined whether or not daylight saving time should be used, the
>   value will be Unknown.   Since: 1.1

If you would like to determine it your own, without this attribute, you have to know the country where to point is, because DST is country specific.

Comment: Thanks actually the idea is i am saving the suffix and offset from API into the database against a spot world wide...so that when ever in future i want to retrieve the spot info i should get the local time accordingly. The API indeed specify the daylight saving attribute but in future i will be not able to find from the database that its indeed a daylight saving there or not.