# Converting Time to a specified country Time Zone

Tags: c#, datetime

i have hosted a site on a server that have different time zone than my local country,

how can I convert the server time to my local time with taking into consideration the Daylight Saving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx) class. You should be able to convert to and from local to server time through there whilst maintaining DST.

There is also an Open Source time zone implementation by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) et. al call [Noda-Time](http://code.google.com/p/noda-time/).

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTimeOffset newTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AppTimeZone"));
```

Answer (score 2):

to blatantly take answers from other SO questions:

In .NET 3.5, there is [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx), which provides a lot of functionality in this area; 2.0SP1 has [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), but this is much more limited.

See the following SO questions:

[Get DateTime For Another Time Zone Regardless of Local Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441109/get-datetime-for-another-time-zone-regardless-of-local-time-zone)

[Convert UTC DateTime to another Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548235/convert-utc-datetime-to-another-time-zone)

Or just search [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c#%20determine%20time%20zone) for a lot of answers including some that take into consideration [Daylight Savings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374988/finding-daylight-saving-indication-based-on-offset-and-suffix-of-time-zone).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [TimeZone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx) class to convert from the server's local time to UTC, then from UTC to your (or the particular website user's) time zone.